# Configure route to api to subfolder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, routes

i'm developing a webapi using MVC 4.
I have a doubt about routers.
How to route to a subfolder under my site. For example:

> www.site.com/Service

My WebApi app is on service folder. My Main Page works fine, but the API is not found.

Here is my route by default:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I want to call

> www.site.com/Service/api/{controller}/{id}

Is there a way to do this?

[Edit]
I added Service area into Ares folder, because already exists a area to HelpPage in the template for WebApi MVC 4.
Inside this folder i added the controlers.

Here is the Service area class

```
public class ServiceAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Service";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Service_default",
            "Service/api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I dont know if this help, my site www.site.com is just a web site, i added and converted this folder Service into application on my iis.
[/Edit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create your own `AreaRegistration` like below to make it work.

```
 public class ServiceAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get{ return "Service";}
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ServiceDefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "Service/api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

You also need to make sure you have below code in `Application_Start()`

```
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

Update:
Your folder structure should looks like:

[image]

Comment: Wich namespace i should add this class?

Comment: You can put the `ServiceAreaRegistration` class inside your `Global.asax` file.

Comment: I added a area to my project and i'm sure i have that code on Application_Start(). And it didnt work. =/

Comment: Make sure you have a folder call `Service`, also your Web API controller is inside that folder.

Comment: Why are you using AreaRegistration with Web API to begin with? Areas is a MVC concept.

Comment: I have the folder Service inside the Areas folder and my controller is inside Service folder

Comment: @KiranChalla i hava this site that root (www.site.com) is only a website and inside of this site i convert a folder called Service to application using IIS.

Comment: @KiranChalla, AreaRegistration is not only for MVC.

Comment: @Lin: Actually it is...To check it for yourself, you just install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` package into an empty Web Application project and see if you can use the type `AreaRegistration`...that said , the reason i even commented originally is that the post doesn't mention about Areas and so didn't feel it right to be used...if there are Areas already, then yeah..what you mentioned makes sense..

Comment: @KiranChalla,@KiranChalla, I got what your mean, because AreaRegistaration class is in the System.Web.Mvc namespace.For example, if OP is using Web API self host, 
the AreaRegistaration class can't be used. That make sense.

Comment: @RenatoRamosNascimento, does your web api controller's path look like this: Areas-> Controller -> YourWebApiController?

Comment: @Lin Its look like AreaName/Controller/MyWebApiController.

Comment: @RenatoRamosNascimento, I'm not sure what your folder structure look like. I updated my answer, if is same to yours, the code what I provided to you should work. You may not need the `ServiceAreaRegistration ` in your `Areas` folder. Just put the above code in the `Global.asax` file.